# check in java netbeans if a database exists in sql server

Tags: sql-server, netbeans-8

I work with sql server as database in Java NetBeans and I want to create a database from Java, before doing this I need to check if it exists or not, I know that the sql syntax is large different from MySQL syntax so at the begining I did this sql syntax:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS
```

But it returns error so please can you tell how to check if it exist in this case it will not be created and if not exists how to create one. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to use [DB_ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx):

```
IF DB_ID(N'YourDBName') IS NULL
CREATE DATABASE YourDBName ....;
```

> Returns the database identification (ID) number.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {  
                          String sql = "SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = '"+base+"'"; 
                        pstt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                        rs = pstt.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()){
                            System.out.println("Database exist");
                        }
                        else{
                           String sqll = "CREATE DATABASE "+base; 
                        pstt=conn.prepareStatement(sqll);
                        pstt.executeUpdate(); 
                        }
                                      }
                                      catch(Exception e){

                                      }
```

i've tried this and it works fine with me, any way thanks for your reply